# Applescript - Copy from specific word to end of TextEdit document / another word

Tags: applescript, textedit

I'd like to know if there's a faster way of copying a range of text from a TextEdit document without having to use so many system events to find, cmd+shift+down and copy the range of text (for cases from word -> end of document).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be too simplistic for what you're looking for but it should at least get you started in the right direction.

```
set yourText to "This is some test text that you might want to work with."
set i to offset of "test" in yourText
set finalText to characters i thru -1 of yourText as string
```

As a side note, I see many people doing things within applications like TextEdit when they don't really need to. In other words, if you're just trying to get the content, there is no reason to open the file in TextEdit (or similar) and script that, you can just read the text file into a variable and then work with your content.

As an example, your script could look something like this...

```
on run
    set yourText to read file "Macintosh SSD:Users:myuser:Desktop:myTextFile.txt"
    set i to offset of "test" in yourText
    set finalText to characters i thru -1 of yourText as string
end run
```

Comment: In AppleScript itself you should use `text i thru j of someString` to get a substring. Alas, sending the same request to TextEdit will fail because its Text Suite support is guff; third-party apps like TextWrangler and Tex-Edit Plus are a much better choice if available. Getting `characters i thru j of ...` from TextEdit has murderously bad performance, because you're asking it to return a list of single-character strings. Lastly, coercing the list down to a single string will also give unpredictable results unless you take care always to set AppleScript's text item delimiters to `""` first.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not; Cocoa Scripting's Text Suite support is abysmal, and doesn't support text range specifiers (e.g. `text (word N) thru end of document ...`), text styles, moving/duplicating/deleting sections of text (at least not without screwing up), or anything else that'd make it reasonably useful.

You don't say what you're actually trying to achieve, but I assume it involves rich text (e.g. .rtf) files otherwise you'd just use StandardAdditions' `read` command to read plain text directly into AS and manipulate it there, so you may want to look into one of the following alternatives:

1. OS X Services, which you can write in Automator and bind to keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences, allowing selected text to be read and processed
2. a third-party scriptable text editor that implements its own Text Suite that doesn't suck
3. `NSData`+`NSAttributedString` which you can use via ObjC/Swift/AppleScript-ObjC/whatever to read .rtf files and work with their contents directly.

Comment: I'm actually transferring files from SAP report formats that are downloaded as txt files, into excel files, some of which are really long so I want to try only copying from a point onwards.

Comment: That sounds singularly nasty. I recommend you back right up, and start by asking around for help with exporting SAP reports in a better format? Or, if you have no control over how data's exported, asking for pointers to existing scripts/libraries/apps you could use to post-process SAP wharrgarble into sane format? I seriously doubt you're the first (or last) person ever to have to deal with such lousy makework crap, and rolling your own solution should be the last option on your list, with AppleScript as the worst possible choice for doing it.